# Appending a variable to divs when I click on the div itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can't seem to get this to work have tried using the this in jquery but it doesn't work any idea would be great. I am aiming at the variable changing on a click and then appending on next click of the <'div'>. These should be independent and I have the code for switching the variable.

Cheers Ferg

HTML

```
<div id="en">test</div>
<div id="de">testing</div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me"></input>
```

Javascript

```
var lang='de';

$('#en').click(function (){
  lang='en';
});

$('#de').click(function (){
  lang='de';
});

$(function(){
  var NewContent='<div class="added">Added</div>'
  $(this).click(function(){
      $("#spin").after(NewContent);
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/Su3RC/104/)

Cheers Again

Update

I have updated the fiddle here to be clearer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/Su3RC/117/) i want to be able to specify which div the variable goes into.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do with the `lang` variable? Also, `#spin` is not in the example HTML you have, that's why the append does not work.

Comment: The `lang` variable is changing, but there's nothing to iniate the `.after()` bit of code...

Comment: where is "spin" element?? and what $(this) is pointing to?? see here http://jsfiddle.net/sourcecode/Su3RC/107/ .. and what you want give clearly..

Comment: Sorry guys the spin is where i was putting the 'this' bit of code. I copied this form somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this is what you want (JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/vgATZ/):

HTML

```
<a href="#en">english</a>
<br>
<a href="#de">german</a>
<br><br>
<div class="gogo">Test div 1</div>
<div class="gogo">Test div 2</div>
```

JS

```
var lang='de';

$('a[href="#en"]').click(function () {
    lang='en';
    return false;
});

$('a[href="#de"]').click(function () {
    lang='de';
    return false;
});

$("div.gogo").click(function(){
  var newContent='<div class="added">Added '+lang+'</div>';
    $(this).append(newContent);
});
```

Comment: thats great and if I want to turn the href's into buttons shall I just use the button id or the input id?

Comment: Yes, Button- or Input-ID both works fine. You can also use the button/input name if you want to, e.g.: $a('button[name="selectEng"]')

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing adding something like this would work for you:

```
$("div").click(function(){
  var newContent='<div class="added">Added '+lang+'</div>';
    $('body').append(newContent);
});
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle here to be clearer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/Su3RC/117/) i want to be able to specifiy which div the variable goes into.